# Is it possible to make a gradient follow a path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient, path

If you take this image:  [image: spiral image]

Is it possible to make a gradient in Illustrator that follows that path? 
I made something similar (just not with a single path, but with the pen tool) and I want to have the gradient follow the shape, but instead it just goes either linear (top to bottom) or radial (from the inside out). I want to have the start of the spiral lighter and than the tip in the center to be darker.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on AI version....

Comment: I have Illustrator CS6.

Comment: You should differentiate the PATH and SHAPE which is in your case may be expanded path. I answered the Q assuming you have a path, and if you don't -  create it :)

Answer (score 19):

Look at the images - you choose the same options and get the result -

You select the path and invoke GRADIENT panel where you choose between 3 STROKE options according to the desired effect:

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Ilan it's the correct answer, but I think it's lacking textual content. Search engines will only be able to read: `Look at the images - you choose the same options and get the result - or or` as the answer. Answering all how-to's like this will negatively impact SEO. I really wish you would write out some step-by-step instructions for your answers.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter Added text explanation with keywording.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a "Apply gradient along stroke" setting in the Gradient panel of Illustrator CC. My current version is 20.0.0. Just adding this for googlers.

[image: Gradient Panel > Add gradient along stroke]

Answer (score 0):

I'm creator of [ruri.design/splines](https://ruri.design/splines) that allows to do same thing and more:

- it's free
- works more like a brush, that you draw with path tool
- you can change shape thats used for drawing curve

Here are some samples i've created with it [image]

Disclosure - this is self promo, if you feel it does not fit here, i'll remove it.

Comment: You, hopefully, realize that Adobe Illustrator is a **vector** application. Your web-based app appears to only export a raster format (PNG). Or I'm unable to find any mechanism to change that. While the physical operation of creating a path and applying a gradient to it, is nice in your app. The lack of *actual vector output* makes this completely miss the point of the question. For *raster* output there are dozens of application capable of a gradient along a path. I don't feel this actually answers the question.

Comment: @Scott You, hopefully, realise that 'gradient across path' effect is NOT supported by SVG format, therefore when exporting it from Illustrator, you get false impression of getting SVG, where in fact you get png;base64 image wrapped within <svg> tag. Using SVG like this is basically same as using PNG.

Comment: Yes. But there's **nothing** in the question about actual usage.. It asked how to in **illustrator**, a vector editor. You are making a leap to assume SVG is wanted or desired. What if the user is designing for *print* and needs vector output? As I commented, if you *want* a png then your tool may be great, but if you *want* vector its not viable. I'm **not** trying to be defamatory towards your tool. I'm merely saying, at face value, it's *not* a good tool if vector output **is** desired.

Comment: It can be frustrating when developers overlook the *entire point* of working in vector. Just because something is possible in raster formats, that does not mean it's automatically viable substitute to working in vector. At best, it's a "as good as possible" substitute. (Note event huge corporations fall into this same pitfall at times.) If an entire piece is vector and this user needs a gradient along a path.. the *best* they could do with your app, is export a PNG and then use raster content in their vector layout.

Comment: In short... far be it for me to tell someone they can't self-promote. It's perfectly fine here with disclosure. But, first and foremost should be to *actually* answer the posed question, which this does not in my opinion. But I'm just user, same as you.

Comment: @Scott I'll put it like this:
+ If you want to create 'gradient across path' in Illustrator, then, yes, Illustrator is best tool
+ If you want to create 'gradient across path' in vector format, there is no such thing. Simply because svg(Scalable Vector Graphics) standart do not support it. No matter you need it for print, web, business card.. Exported vector file (pdf, svg, ...) will be pixel based. So there is no difference where you create it, in Illustrator or Photoshop..

Comment: You seem to be stuck on SVG. There are thousands, if not millions, of designers who have never needed or used the SVG format. There are many other formats than merely what webDev will support SVG isn't viable for *print* design in most cases. And ultimately *everything* ends up raster, print or web. The difference is is *working within the construction of the file*. Your tool, just exports a PNG... there's no easy method to integrate a PNG with other vector construction. That's my point. If the **only** thing needed is a gradient on path, sure your tool seems great.

Comment: @Scott there are millions who don't want to work with Illustrator either. As a designer, I love to use standarts, that are viable across different platforms - Sketch, Figma, Illustrator and those are formats like svg, png, jpg.

Comment: But **this question** asks about **Illustrator**. Which is why I feel this isn't actually an answer to the **posed question**. If the question asked about Photoshop or a raster editor, I think it's 100% solid answer. But it's *not* for a question about a *vector* editor. One doesn't ask.. How do I replace the alternator in my 1992 Chevy Truck.. then answer .. Well you can replace the alternator in a 2002 Toyota Celica like this.... -- We'll simply have to agree to disagree `:)`

Comment: @Scott i've found this conversation via reddit where someone else referenced to this question but asking for different tool. We all win if we know that there are different options out there. Not all who land here are so strict of having IL. https://www.reddit.com/r/FigmaDesign/comments/mx20zk/gradient_along_path/

Comment: ahh so *that's* why you want to self-promote here 8 years after the question was asked..... to boost your SEO .. even if the answer isn't relevant to the question. m'kay `:)`