# How to fill a closed path with a gradient that follows a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is a follow up to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41564/5795) where they describe the procedure about how to "paint" a gradient that follows a path. So, my question is whether this could be used to fill a closed shape like the one in the figure bellow, where the left side of the hand has a linear gradient that does not reflect the curvature of the contours.

[image]

Comment: Look up gradient meshes - https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html

Comment: @BillyKerr It seems that's the way to go, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 3 different ways of doing thing.

1) Use a radial gradient that follows the contour of the hand.

[image: radial gradient example]

2) Use a gradient mesh

3) Use a very thick stroke and use a linear gradient. Use a clipping mask to hide the ends of the stroke. Then use a gradient on the hand to fill the left thumb with the shadow color.

[image: stroke gradient example]

Comment: I see... in number 3 I can also make the path 4 or 5 times thicker, so it occupies the entire hand, and repeat the shadow and light colors at about 40% and 60% of the gradient bar.