# Make a gradient follow a specific path on a shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, path, gradient

I'm a beginner AI user and what I'm trying to do is to make a gradient follow a path on a specific shape. This is the shape, I want to fade it from the line to the end of the loop:

[image]

The shade would simply be from white to transparent and it should start fading from the red line to the end of the loop.

If I simply apply the gradient to fill the shape it goes from left to right at whatever angle is given, but I want it to follow that specific path. I already found [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41564/is-it-possible-to-make-a-gradient-follow-a-path-in-illustrator) question but I don't have an actual inner path, it's more of a shape filled with white and with no stroke.

Is there a way to do so?

Thank you for the help, have a good day.

Comment: Yeah you can put a gradient on a path in newer illustrators

Comment: I posted [an answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/116357/89608) to a similar question. It may be of some use to you if your version of Illustrator doesn't have gradient on a path functionality.  It's quite possible to recreate it manually. My answer was for Inkscape but the same could be done in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this in Illustrator would be to use a gradient on path outline (stroke), instead of shape. (Post CS6)

You will have to recreate your path as a line instead of a shape.

Draw a path in the shape you want then apply a gradient to the stroke.

In the Gradient Panel **Window→Gradient** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>), you want to switch it to *Apply gradient along stroke*

[image: img]

You will want to set the stroke thickness up in order to see your result.

Here's a quick one I did:

[image: sample]

---

I recognize that converting that shape into a path is actually quite challenging, here's a rough (eyeballed) [sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/master/Saved/SVG/InfinitySymbol.svg) you can use, I'm sure there's a more mathematical way to create this, but here's the [Illustrator file](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/raw/master/Saved/IllustratorFiles/InfinitySymbolCreation.ait) where you can see the process I used to create it.

Comment: Yes, it was quite challenging indeed, and I managed to recreate it (almost) manually but I'll use your SVG since its better than what I did. Anyway, your hints helped me, but in order to get the gradient follow the path I had to use the `Apply gradient accross stroke`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yep, I'll sure take a look, thank you!